# I can open omnibus but my co-worker can't

Tags: gmail, file-conversion, windows-10

My co-worker and I belong to the same G Suite. She received an attachment that she couldn't open (no visible file type). She forwarded the email message to me.  I checked the file type but there appeared to be none.  I work remote.  We are both running Windows 10. I have 7zip installed on my computer, but didn't explicitly invoke it. She doesn't have 7zip.

Reading the email message, I saw one attachment. I couldn't tell if it had a file type extension or not.  When I downloaded the ONE attachment, and went to the folder where I stored it, lo and behold, there were two items -- one was a pdf and the other was a mystery file with no extension. After the file name, there were parentheses and the word "omnibus" like this:

`clerk response (omnibus)`

On a hunch that it was an email message, I edited the file name and added

`.eml`

Then I edited it with notepad++ and indeed, it was a perfectly legible email message.

My procedure didn't work for her. We did a screen share and I watched her try.  It just didn't show up as two items for her.

My guess is that the attachment was an OMB file. If so, what procedure can I come up with for her to be able to open such things without assistance? Does something in her Gmail need to be tweaked?  Some setting on her computer?  Something needing to be installed?

Comment: If you could post the link to the file you received, I can help you get an easier way to open such files in future.

Comment: @Ankit - what do you have in mind?  (I can't give you access to the file, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

*(First of all it is not related to Gmail.)*

**What is an `OMB` file extension?**

`OMB` or `.omb` is the extension for the `Omnibus Offline Web Storage data`  files by [Alfega Technologies, Inc](https://www.bizapedia.com/nv/alfega-technologies-inc.html).

As mentioned on the net *"this format seems to be obsolete and no longer supported"*.

Elsewhere that *"these OMB files are popular with users from United States and most frequently found on the Windows 10 platform"*

**How to open .omb files**

*"On a hunch that it was an email message"* Since it worked, it is a good procedure.
It is probably because you *"have 7zip installed"*, you could open the file.

Since the site [alfega.com](http://www.alfega.com/) no longer exists it is quite difficult to find a program dedicated to opening this extension.

It seems though you can open them online on the [filext.com](https://filext.com/file-extension/OMB) site (untested)

As for *"She received an attachment that she couldn't open (no visible file type)"*, please read how to [Show and hide file extensions in Windows 10](https://www.google.gr/search?newwindow=1&hl=en&q=Show+and+hide+file+extensions+in+Windows+10)

**Internet Sources**

- [What is File Extension OMB?](https://www.fileviewpro.com/en/file-extension-omb/)
- [whatext.com](https://whatext.com/omb)
- [filext.com](https://filext.com/file-extension/OMB)
- [web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20081212130718/http://www.alfega.com/omnibus-overview.html)
- [file-extensions.org](https://www.file-extensions.org/omb-file-extension#description)
- [bizapedia.com](https://www.bizapedia.com)
- [www.filesuffix.com](https://www.filesuffix.com/en/extension/omb)

Comment: Thanks, but there really was no file type.  I did show her with a screenshare how to display file extensions.

Comment: You asked for *"My guess is that the attachment was an OMB file. If so, what ..."* and *"She received an attachment that she couldn't open (no visible file type)."* That is what the answer resolves. So both your questions were addressed. **Please remember** that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Comment: I've edited the question to try to make things clearer re the file type.

Comment: *"I've edited the question to try to make things clearer re the file type."*. Could you please tell me which part of your updated question is not covered by the answer given, so I can look into it? If none, it would be nice to accept it as is.

Comment: By starting a bounty you wanted to draw more attention. Attention was drawn. A reaction  to my latest comment within the bounty period would be appreciated.